# Scrollable canvas not working, content larger than window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scroll

I am very new to Tkinter and a novice at Python.

The aim is to display a window with scrollable contents. Presently the contents of the canvas go outside the window. the window has to be resized to see all the content. The scrollbar doesn't work.

Changing the dimensions of the canvas has no effect.

What changes should I make to fix this issue?

Minimal code:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *

class AnnotatorGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, table_content):

    Frame.__init__(self, master=master)

    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid(sticky=W + E + N + S)
    for x in range(1,100):
        line_content_text = Text(self.master, width=100, height=1)
        line_content_text.insert(INSERT, table_content)
        line_content_text.grid(row=x, column=1, sticky=W + E + N + S)

def gui_annotate():

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=170, height=300)
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

# A few things to scroll
canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill='blue', outline='red')
canvas.create_rectangle(60,460,100,500,fill='blue', outline='red')

table_content = ['content']
gui = AnnotatorGui(canvas, table_content)

canvas.config(yscrollcommand= vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()


def main():
        gui_annotate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Complete code:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

from keras_en_parser_and_analyzer.library.dl_based_parser import line_types, line_labels
from keras_en_parser_and_analyzer.library.utility.io_utils import read_pdf_and_docx

class AnnotatorGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, table_content):

    Frame.__init__(self, master=master)

    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid(sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.line_index_label_list = []
    self.line_content_text_list = []
    self.line_type_button_list = []
    self.line_label_button_list = []

    for line_index, line in enumerate(table_content):
        self.build_line(table_content, line_index, line)

    self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


def build_line(self, table_content, line_index, line):
    line_content = line[0]

    line_index_label = Label(self.master, width=10, height=1, text=str(line_index))
    line_index_label.grid(row=line_index, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)
    line_content_text = Text(self.master, width=100, height=1)
    line_content_text.insert(INSERT, line_content)
    line_content_text.grid(row=line_index, column=1, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    def line_type_button_click(_line_index):
        line_type = table_content[_line_index][1]
        line_type = (line_type + 1) % len(line_types)
        table_content[_line_index][1] = line_type
        line_type_button["text"] = "Type: " + line_types[line_type]

    def line_label_button_click(_line_index):
        line_label = table_content[_line_index][2]
        line_label = (line_label + 1) % len(line_labels)
        table_content[_line_index][2] = line_label
        line_label_button["text"] = "Type: " + line_labels[line_label]

    line_type_button = Button(self.master, text="Type: Unknown", width=20,
                              command=lambda: line_type_button_click(line_index))
    line_type_button.grid(row=line_index, column=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)
    line_label_button = Button(self.master, text='Label: Unknown', width=20,
                               command=lambda: line_label_button_click(line_index))
    line_label_button.grid(row=line_index, column=3, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    if line[1] != -1:
        line_type_button["text"] = "Type: " + line_types[line[1]]
    if line[2] != -1:
        line_label_button["text"] = "Type: " + line_labels[line[2]]



def command_line_annotate(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content):
    with open(os.path.join(training_data_dir_path, str(index) + '.txt'), 'wt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line_index, line in enumerate(file_content):
            print('Line #' + str(line_index) + ': ', line)
            data_type = input('Type for line #' + str(line_index) + ' (options: 0=header 1=meta 2=content):')
            label = input('Label for line #' + str(line_index) +
                          ' (options: 0=experience 1=knowledge 2=education 3=project 4=others 5=skills 6=awards')
            data_type = int(data_type)
            label = int(label)
            f.write(line_types[data_type] + '\t' + line_labels[label] + '\t' + line)
            f.write('\n')

def guess_line_type(line):
    return -1


def guess_line_label(line):
    return -1


def gui_annotate(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content):
    root = Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(root, width=170, height=500, scrollregion=(0,0,100,500))
    vsb= Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview, width=12)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + S)
vsb.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
vsb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand= vsb.set)   
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

table_content = [[line, guess_line_type(line), guess_line_label(line)] for line in file_content]
gui = AnnotatorGui(canvas, table_content)

def callback():
    root.destroy()
    output_file_path = os.path.join(training_data_dir_path, str(index) + '.txt')
    if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
        return
    with open(output_file_path, 'wt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in table_content:
            line_content = line[0]
            data_type = line[1]
            label = line[2]

            if data_type == -1 or label == -1:
                continue

            print('write line: ', line)
            f.write(line_types[data_type] + '\t' + line_labels[label] + '\t' + line_content)
            f.write('\n')

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)
gui.mainloop()


def main():
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    current_dir = current_dir if current_dir is not '' else '.'

    data_dir_path = current_dir + '/data'  # directory to scan for any pdf files
    training_data_dir_path = current_dir + '/data/training_data'
    collected = read_pdf_and_docx(data_dir_path, 

command_logging=True, callback=lambda index, file_path, file_content: {
        gui_annotate(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content)
})

print('count: ', len(collected))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's difficult to bugfix without the code which produces the error. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've edited the code to be complete

Comment: It would help if this code didn't have to rely on an external file. Can't you simulate the problem with a simple loop and a counter? Also, please try to remove all of the code that is unnecessary to duplicate the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for the suggestion, I've added a minimal working code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is not correct an there's som libraries I do not have. However: I played around a bit with the previous code and came up with:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=170, height=300)
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill='blue', outline='red')
canvas.create_rectangle(60,460,100,500,fill='blue', outline='red')
# Add a Text widget with create_window
line_content_text = Text(root, width=20, height=1)
line = canvas.create_window(40, 160, height=20, width=90, window=line_content_text)

# Define scrollregion AFTER widgets are placed on canvas
padding = (-50, -50, 50, 50)
region = [x+y for (x,y) in zip(canvas.bbox("all"),padding)]
canvas.config(yscrollcommand= vsb.set, scrollregion=region)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help. The content fits inside the canvas perfectly now although the scrollbar still doesn't work

Comment: Took a while to see it..., You're not actually putting the Text widgets on canvas, but rather using `grid()`. You will have to use `canvas.create_window()` to place them on the canvas. Since they are not on canvas `canvas.bbox("all")` is `None` and the scrollregion does not work.

Comment: Changed example to include `canvas.create_window()`. You will have to figure out the sizes etc. yourself as you might need to adjust size of window on canvas depending on font size.

Comment: Awesome. I think I've figured it out, made it work for the minimal code sample. I've been stuck at this for days. Thank you so much. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: @AshokNarendranath Can you please put the working code here ? I am also getting the same issue for the same code. And not really sure where exactly I have to put the below suggestion. Thanks.